# Loop through an SVG using JS

Tags: javascript, css, svg

So I have a small star SVG that I made, and I'm trying to use that star instead of styling a span to make a bunch of bubbles float up to the top of my div.  I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get my Javascript loop to instead use an SVG to make my bubbles, instead of the span.

```
"use strict";

// variables
var numBubbles = 60;
var minSize = 10;
var maxSize = 20;
var container = document.getElementById("container");

// get the size of a bubble
// Randomized between minSize and maxSize
function bubbleSize() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxSize - minSize + 1)) + minSize;
}

// Get the location of a bubble.
// Between left=2% and left=98%.
function bubbleLocation() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 96) + 2;
}

// Create a bubble using the
// previous two functions.
function createBubble() {
  var size = bubbleSize();
  var location = bubbleLocation();

  // create span
  var el = document.createElement("span");

  // style span
  el.setAttribute("style", "width: " + size + "px; height: " + size + "px; left: " + location + "%; box-shadow: " + "0px 0px 12px 2px #ff4e85;");

  // append span
  container.appendChild(el);

}

// Start adding bubbles.
(function startBubbles() {
  var i = 0;

  function addBubble() {
    if (i < numBubbles) {
      createBubble();
      i++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(inter);
    }
  }

  // Add a bubble every 500ms.
  // But we don't want too many bubbles...

  var inter = setInterval(addBubble, 300);

})();
```

https://codepen.io/smugfox/pen/KyNxLG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either clone a lot of SVGs using [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) in `createBubble()`...

```
var el = svg.cloneNode(true);
```

..or you can keep using `<span>`s, and set the SVG as `background-image` in CSS:

```
span {
    background-image: url("/path/to/star.svg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    ...
```

Either way, if you want a drop-shadow on your star, you need to do that using a `<filter>` in the SVG file.

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/YEpbwZ
*Uses cloned SVGs. Change `cloneSVGs` to `false` to use spans with background image.*

Comment: Wow!  thank you for the help Sphinxxx.  I really appreciate it.